# Form with enctype='multipart/form-data' resulting in 'Premature end of script headers' error

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, apache, passenger

Users on my Rails application must attach an XML file when creating a new object. This action works fine in development (Windows), but in production (Unix) the following error is thrown.

> Premature end of script headers: namespace, referer: X.X.X.X/namespace/objects/new

Where X.X.X.X is the IP address.

I've determined that the controller action is never reached and this error arises after the form is submitted. I am using Rails' `form_for` tag, which looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @object, url: new_object_path, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |form| %>
    <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { form: form }  %>
<% end %>
```

And the form partial has this file upload field:

```
<%= form.file_field :xml, accept: '.xml', required: true %>
```

This generates the following HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/namespace/objects" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_object" method="post">
     ...
     <input accept=".xml" id="object_xml" name="object[xml]" required="required" type="file">
     ...
</form>
```

To me, this looks like a perfectly reasonable form, but it's throwing this odd error. If I remove the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` the error disappears and the controller action is called! This creates another problem where the controller action just receives the file name and not the uploaded file itself, but hey, at least we're hitting the controller action now and I've pinpointed the issue.

So my question is: why is this seemingly reasonable, auto-generated Rails form and its enctype field causing this (extremely vague and unhelpful) error to be thrown?

Here's the software we're using.

- Phusion Passenger 4.0.41
- Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.2
- Chef 10.24.0
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 4.1.4
- JRuby 1.7.16

Comment: Look like it is Apache config issue

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I'm not too familiar with Apache outside of the basics, so I wasn't sure what I needed to include or take out of the config. Do I need to somehow allow file uploads? Searching around the Internet hasn't provided much insight.

Comment: I use Nginx + Puma, so not sure. Google show me this, not sure if related: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache%204.0.html#_upload_progress

Comment: That looks to be a progress tracker for file uploads, which doesn't seem to be related to this issue.